# Choose active tool in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to choose active tool in Python?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`wm.tool_set_by_id()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id) operator.

[image]

Example for a button:

```
layout.operator("wm.tool_set_by_id").name = "builtin.select_box"
```

Example operator:

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name = "builtin.move")
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: you can call the operator inside another operator or as in my first example you can add button to a menu/panel.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can set it active tool via [`bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id) operator. However it is important to execute the operator in the right context. So running this operator from the wrong context won't work. Here is a simple method that sets the tool with the right context override:

```
def set_active_tool(tool_name):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            override = bpy.context.copy()
            override["space_data"] = area.spaces[0]
            override["area"] = area
            bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(override, name=tool_name)
```

If you want to know how the active `tool_name` is called, just go into the console and type in `bpy.context.workspace.tools` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This will show you the current and last active tool id name which you can use as parameter for your `set_active_tool()` method. Just select your desired tool and see how it is called.

Comment: But, would it be possible to have no active tool (like set_active_tool to 'None')?