# It is possible to change between 3D_cursor and selection_box using python script?

Tags: python, scripting

It is possible to change between 3D_cursor and selection_box using python script?
There is no code because I don't have any idea on how to swap 3d cursor with select_box in python and vice versa.
Is there any short method for this?

[image]

Comment: please add some details

Comment: @yhoyo I did now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose active tool in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135738/choose-active-tool-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when this was introduced, but as of Blender 2.9x you can use [`bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id) to change between the tools.  The ID for the selection box is "builtin.select_box" so you would switch to it by

```
bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.select_box")
```

You do have to be in the 3D Viewport for this command to work of course.